# FTP over TLS via BitBucket Pipelines

Tags: hosting, bitbucket-pipelines, lftp

I can't seem to get this working, hoping somebody can help.

This is my bitbucket-pipelines.yml file:

```
image: cschlosser/alpine-lftps
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          deployment: production
          script:
            lftp -d -e "mirror --reverse . $FTP_TARGET_PATH" -p $FTP_PORT -u $FTP_USERNAME,$FTP_PASSWORD $FTP_TARGET_SITE
```

This is the error I get:

```
+ lftp -d -e "mirror --reverse . $FTP_TARGET_PATH" -p $FTP_PORT -u $FTP_USERNAME,$FTP_PASSWORD $FTP_TARGET_SITE
---- Resolving host address...
---- 2 addresses found: XXXX:bXXX:4::23, XXX.XX.XX.XX
---- Connecting to xxx.hostxxx.net (XXXX:bXXX:4::23) port 21
**** connect(control_sock): Address not available
---- Closing control socket
---- Connecting to xxx.hostxxx.net (XXX.XX.XX.XX) port 21
**** SSL_connect: wrong version number
---- Closing control socket
mirror: Fatal error: SSL_connect: wrong version number
```

I am able to connect to the FTP account via a client, so it's something to do with this pipeline/ lftp.  I can't find how to enable SSL on this alpine-lftps script, or should that just work?

Comment: It looks like the setting cmd:default-protocol is set to FTPS. Is it what you want to use?

Comment: Yes I believe FTPS is what my host FTP requires.  In my FTP Client, I set it to use FTP-SSL (Explicit Auth TLS) which works.. don't know how to set that via this Alpine-lftps script.  Any ideas?

Comment: FTPS is for implicit ssl.

Comment: FTPS is for implicit ssl. Don't set cmd:default-protocol in rc scripts or use explicit ftp url like this: ftp://host:port

Comment: Yeah I've tried the :PORT on the URL (using 21, 23)... doesn't work. Can you specify exactly what you think i should be using so i can try that?

Comment: SO mangled the URL, it should have ftp:// at the beginning

Comment: Yeah, nah that didn't work. I've tried every combination I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

I got it!  Only took me 54 builds to get there.

The answer came from this post here:
  https://serverfault.com/questions/411970/how-to-avoid-lftp-certificate-verification-error/727003

My final working script looks like this:

```
- lftp ftp://$FTP_USERNAME@$FTP_HOST -e "set ssl:verify-certificate no; mirror --reverse $SOURCE_PATH $FTP_TARGET_PATH; quit"  -u $FTP_USERNAME,$FTP_PASSWORD
```

The pertinent part is the **set ssl:verify-certificate no;**

Since I don't have much experience with lftp, I'd appreciate any feedback on this script.. anything I can improve would be greatly appreciated.